# Parameters in stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here,when I am passing correct and incorrect value,both the times I am getting result as 4

When I am executing this query

```
select Count(*) into result 
from document_details 
where document_name = name 
and document_path = path;
```

then it shows me correct answer which is 1.
Kindly help me ASAP. Thank You in advance!!

```
create procedure check_status(IN name INT(30),IN path INT(255))    
    BEGIN
    declare result int;
    set result = 0;
    select Count(*) into result from `document_details` where `document_name`=name and `document_path`=path;
    select result;

END
```

Comment: Did you intend to declare both input parameters as INT?

Comment: m so sry..Really a silly n stupid mistake..
Thanks a ton!! @jaczes and John

Answer (score 0):

IF types are OK, then that shoud work id not, change then into i.e. `(name CHAR(30),path CHAR(255))`

```
create procedure check_status(name INT(30),path INT(255))    
BEGIN

select Count(*) as result from `document_details` 
where `document_name`=name and     `document_path`=path;

END;
```

In procedures there is no `IN`/`OUT` in funcions there are...

Comment: "In procedures there is no IN/OUT in funcions there are..." No, it's the other way round ;)